# Need help coding jQuery for draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm taking a course online and we're studying draggables.  This is the code that the instructor used (maybe i did something wrong) to make a square draggable.  It's not working for me in firefox or chrome.  What is wrong with my code.

The jQuery file is in the same folder with my html file. I copied his api link per his instructions and not from google api library.  The lessons are old.

Would appreciate it if someone check my code and see if it works for them.

Thanks for the help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<style>

    #square {

    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:grey;

    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="square"></div>



<script>

    $("square").draggable();




</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the hashtag in the

```
$("square").draggable();
```

So write it like this:

```
$("#square").draggable();
```

Because the div has an id.
Remember to use a dot (.) when referring to a class and a hashtag (#) when referring to an id.

Comment: use '.' for class selection, '#' for id selection, and tag name (e.g. table) for direct element selection. Exactly the same way CSS works.